# What is a formal synonym phrase for "What the hell are you talking about"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request, expressions, slang

What I want to write is
**formal, or polite version of**

> what **the hell** are you talking about?

A reason why I can't use this is beacuse a person who's saying this is a middle-aged man, and he's not likely to say something like "what the hell.."

And I know  I can just remove "the hell" and go for "what are you talking about?", but it's too simple compared to what I initially wanted to say. I don't know what exactly "hell" means here, but I know it does have some impolite, negative connotations. But here, he isn't being that offensive. He's kind of emphasizing what he had just heard is a total nonsense.

Is there any expression which is a formal version of "what the hell are you talking about" in English?

Or is there any good word that can replace "the hell"?

Comment: As a minced oath, "what the dickens" is often substituted for "what the hell".

Comment: A more formal response would be "I beg you pardon?"

Comment: Whatever ***are***  you talking about? You can italicize the are to indicate emphasis, to sound like it would when said.

Comment: What in heaven's name are you talking about?

Comment: I wouldn't assume that middle-aged men are unlikely to say "what the hell".  It depends on the individual and on the circumstances.

Comment: I'm a middle-aged man (I suppose… [sigh]) and I'd never say “What the hell” — but only because, if circumstances warranted, I'd be more likely to say something a lot stronger!  I think we'd need to know a lot more about the context before we could judge what this hypothetical middle-aged man might say: his time period, background, location, &c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are perhaps several hundred ways to say this, most of which depend on the personality, background, nationality, education, social class, etc. of the person involved.  A colorful example:

> The deuce you say!

This is a British expression dating back to the 17th century where "deuce" is used in place of "devil" ("The devil you say!").  I'm not sure how *formal* it is, but it seems to have been acceptable between Victorian gentlemen (although possibly not when ladies were present).

Apparently it means something more like "I don't believe what you just said!" which can sometimes be the purpose of saying "What the hell are you talking about?"

In a similar way you can often substitute the mild epithet "heck" for "hell":

> What the **heck** are you talking about?

Other possibilities:

> What **in the world** are you saying?
>
> What **on earth** do you mean?
>
> What **in God's name** are you talking about?

More colloquially:

> What **the dickens** are you talking about?
>
> What **in blue blazes** are you talking about?
>
> What **on God's green Earth** are you talking about?

Of course, you can always go the other direction by using *stronger* epithets than "hell".  Feel free to get creative.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of **what the hell**, you can say **what on earth** or **what in the world**.

Answer (score 0):

If you were being very formal, you might use a polite phrase which merely *implies* your scepticism, such as:

- “**Excuse me?**”
- “**That's very interesting…**”
- “**I would *never* have thought of that!**”
- “**Thank you for sharing that.**”
- “**I *beg* your pardon?**”
- “**I'll bear that in mind…**”
- “**I hardly know what to say.**”
- “**What a *novel* idea!**”

(With the right tone, such a remark can be utterly withering yet perfectly polite and hard to take offence at.)